# What kind of IntelliSense support does Visual Studio 2010 have for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

When I type '$('body').', a few generic choices pop up, including toLocalString() method, but not fadeIn() method or most of the specific methods you expect to pop up. So what's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have noticed, Visual Studio has no support whatsoever for *jQuery* Intellisense, per-se. If it did, *you would have seen jQuery-related Intellisense show up*.

However, you can download a vsdoc file to get this support. See [this blog post by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/08/jquery-1-4-1-intellisense-with-visual-studio.aspx) for more.

As the extremely short article states, Visual Studio 2010 has built-in support for *vsdoc* files. It then informs you that you can download the vsdoc file to *get jQuery Intellisense support* from the jQuery website.

Comment: @Aperture No, it does not. It says *support for vsdoc files is built in*. You need to download the vsdoc file for jQuery.